# How to implement background service for chromecast in android

Tags: android, service, chromecast

I have referred https://github.com/ovingalafsal/ChromeCastSampleApp for casting media file using default receiver and default media channel and i have integrated into my existing app which is working fine but which is not running in background when press the home button and lock the phone also. so I want to implement the background service for this, while casting media file with default receiver. So Please guide me to how to handle the background service for casting and create the notification and handle in lock state of the phone. Would be grateful if give any sample or demo for this.

You can refer the code from this https://github.com/ovingalafsal/ChromeCastSampleApp.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Were you able to cast to `chromecast` without user interaction ?

Comment: @siva Hi, I also having same issue. I have connected and cast videos on ChromeCast. Videos are playing fine when app in foreground, but app go for background cast video disconnected and not playing. Can you help me? It is possible or not. If possible means how handle for this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the sample code [CastVideos-android](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android) which does notification and lock screen for you and has a background service for notification. It uses the [CastCompanionLibrary](https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android) for most of the work.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Sorry i am new to chromecast those code is hard to understand and implemented so many functionality. I need simple service for background and make a notification for casting.

Comment: Hi, When do i start the service and make a notification for casting? Kindly tell me the life cycle to start the service when connect the device to casting

Comment: You can read the design documents to see what the recommendation is and then decide when you want to do that; notification is recommended to be visible when application is casting but is not in front.

Comment: So can i just show the notification while casting? and don't need to implement whole process into service?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, if you mean just show the notification while the app is in front, then that would not agree with the Cast recommended UX guidelines. Please review the guidelines at https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/design_checklist

Comment: I need to know the whether the service is need or not for casting?, because i want to show the notification also in status bar while casting if user want to move other app.

Comment: Hi, I also having same issue. I have connected and cast videos on ChromeCast. Videos are playing fine when app in foreground, but app go for background cast video disconnected and not playing. Can you help me? It is possible or not. If possible means how handle for this one.